# What PIC microcontroller can interface with an ADXRS800 gyroscope with SPI output?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, spi, gyro

Straight to the point...

I planning to use an ADXRS800 gyroscope and its output is a 32bit SPI message, does this mean that it can only be interfaced with a 32bit PIC microcontroller, or could i use my 8 bit microcontroller.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can use *any* 8-bit µC.

Messages longer than a byte you can handle in multiple single byte pieces.

Take a look at some example code.
E.g. [here](http://www.microchipc.com/sourcecode/#interface) you can find several examples for interfacing a PIC to various  peripherals.

Answer (score 2):

As Curd said, you can use any microcontroller as long as it has three digital output lines and one digital input line.  The SPI hardware in PICs is limited to transferring whole chunks of 8 bits.  Since you need to transfer a integer multiple of that, you can use the hardware directly.  You just do four 8-bit transfers consecutively.  The 16 bit PICs also have a 16 bit SPI mode where it transfers whole chunks of 16 bits at a time.  That would work for you too, since 32 is a integer multiple of 16.

SPI is a very simple protocol for the master to implement.  Since the master owns the clock, SPI can be easily implemented in firmware.  I've done that a few times, sometimes just to use different pins than the dedicated SPI peripheral.  Of course with a firmware implementation, you can transfer how ever many bits you want in one message.

The native word size of the processor has nothing whatesoever to do with your problem.  That only tells you what size chunk of bits it can operate on at a time.  You can eventually operate on any size number with any processor, just that it will take a bunch of instructions to manipulate words wider than the processor's data paths.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of bits a microcontroller has is the amount of bits it can natively do calculations on. A 8-bit micro can typically multiply, sum, subtract 2 8-bits (byte) in 1 instruction.

If the micro has to do 16-bit or 32-bit calculations, it will compile extra instructions to make that happen. It will make the calculation significantly slower, however, if that would be taking ~400 instructions at 4MIPS (=16MHz PIC16/18), you still be able to process (theoretically) 10KSPS. You probably can always tweak calculations to run faster on your system, so unless you want to do multiple kalman filters, angle sine() calculations you don't really need a really big processor.

(oh btw, couldn't find a datasheet of the sensor, only a summary saying that it outputs 16-bit data words).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the product selector tool to help narrow down your search: http://www.microchip.com/ParamChartSearch/chart.aspx?branchID=1005.

Like those before have already said, many options will work, but this tool helps you think about other constraints (like cost, package, speed, size, etc).